# Find inf,sup, min, and max of the following sets, or show that they don’t exist.

Tags: real-analysis

So we have to find inf,sup, min, and max of the following sets, or show
that they don’t exist.

1) the set of all integers $Z$

inf = $-\infty$ , sup = $\infty$ , max and min don't exists... I can see the answer but Im not sure how to prove it using the definition of epsilon and infimum with completeness

2) the set all natural numbers greater than or equal to $1$  ($n\in N \&n\ge 1$)

inf = 1, sup = $\infty$, min = 1, max = doesn't exists.. but Im not sure how to prove this

Comment: Have you tried reductio ad absurdum? Assume there is a maximum, namely number x, then exists x+1...
Or is it mandatory to prove it by definition?

Comment: Ive looked into this, but this proof i have to prove it using inf/sup with epsilon

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\infty$ and $-\infty $ are not real numbers.

You need to remove those from your answers and replace them with  " does not exist"

Otherwise your solution is correct.